# Django for some reason doesn't want to import one particular model

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model where I'm importing a number of items:

```
from django.db import models
from mcif.models.import_profile import ImportProfile
from mcif.models.import_file import ImportFile
from mcif.models.import_bundle import ImportBundle
from mcif.models.customer import Customer
#from mcif.models.account_import import AccountImport
from mcif.models.csv_row import CSVRow
import csv, cStringIO
```

It works fine, but when I uncomment that line that's commented, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 18, in handle_noargs
    loaded_models = get_models()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/models/loading.py", line 167, in get_models
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/models/loading.py", line 64, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/models/loading.py", line 78, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/jason/projects/mcifdjango/mcif/models/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from mcif.models.account_import import AccountImport
  File "/home/jason/projects/mcifdjango/mcif/models/account_import.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mcif.models.generic_import import GenericImport
  File "/home/jason/projects/mcifdjango/mcif/models/generic_import.py", line 6, in <module>
    from mcif.models.account_import import AccountImport
ImportError: cannot import name AccountImport
```

Why doesn't Django like this one particular file?

(I can load `AccountImport` by itself on the console just fine.)

Also, here's `AccountImport` if it helps to see it:

```
from django.db import models
from mcif.models.generic_import import GenericImport

class AccountImport(models.Model):

    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    generic_import = models.ForeignKey(GenericImport)
    is_entirely_international = models.IntegerField()
    is_queued = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'account_import'
        app_name = 'mcif'
```

And `GenericImport`:

```
from django.db import models
from mcif.models.import_profile import ImportProfile
from mcif.models.import_file import ImportFile
from mcif.models.import_bundle import ImportBundle
from mcif.models.customer import Customer
from mcif.models.csv_row import CSVRow
import csv, cStringIO

class GenericImport(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'generic_import'
        app_name = 'mcif'

    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    import_profile = models.ForeignKey(ImportProfile)
    import_file = models.ForeignKey(ImportFile)
    notes = models.TextField()
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    active = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
    unsavable_rows = models.TextField()
    import_bundle = models.ForeignKey(ImportBundle)
    is_queued = models.IntegerField()

    @classmethod
    def last(cls):
        all = GenericImport.objects.all()
        return all[len(all) - 1]

    def process(self):
        for line in self.import_file.file.split("\n")[:30]:
            f = cStringIO.StringIO(line)
            row = CSVRow()
            row.array = next(csv.reader(f))
            row.generic_import = self
            row.process()
            f.close()

    def specific_import(self):
        for model_name in ['TransactionImport', 'AccountImport']:
            specific_imports = eval(model_name + '.objects.filter(generic_import__pk=5)')
            if len(specific_imports) > 0:
                return specific_imports[0]
        return False
```

Comment: Either you've modified `GenericImport` since you ran into the problem or this is not the right file.  There is no `from mcif.models.account_import import AccountImport` on line 6 of this file.

Comment: Right. I took the commented-out line and just deleted it. Other than that it's identical.

Comment: So have you retried this after that?  If you run into the same error, post the new traceback.  The line obviously wasn't commented out when you ran it the first time, or it wouldn't have executed and shown up in the traceback.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it both ways before I posted the question. If I don't import `AccountImport`, `specific_import()` won't work because `GenericImport` doesn't know about `TransactionImport` or `AccountImport`.

Comment: Yeah, see my updated answer - this is bad design (and it's no coincidence that this won't work).  A better pattern exists, either you can pass in a list of classes to check (still not great) or you can have a separate class that manages this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular import - `mcif.models.generic_import` and `mcif.models.account_import` are trying to import each other.

Remember that Python is not Java, and is quite happy to have multiple classes in a single file, especially if they're closely related like these two seem to be. Put them both in a single `mcif.models` file.

Comment: I hope there's another way. I have over 30 different models, each with its own file. It would seem inconsistent to have just one case where I have two models in the same file. It would also seem irresponsible to put all 30+ models in the same file. Any other suggestions?

Comment: That's no way to write Python, seriously. Models should be split up logically into apps, not all separated into single-class files within a single app.

Comment: Are you saying I should put all the models in one file? If so, how come? (Besides the obvious circular reference problem)

Answer (score 2):

That is a circular model dependency.

```
File "/home/jason/projects/mcifdjango/mcif/models/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from mcif.models.account_import import AccountImport
File "/home/jason/projects/mcifdjango/mcif/models/account_import.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mcif.models.generic_import import GenericImport
File "/home/jason/projects/mcifdjango/mcif/models/generic_import.py", line 6, in <module>
    from mcif.models.account_import import AccountImport
ImportError: cannot import name AccountImport
```

If you really need those models separated, have a look at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey for a solution. Instead of importing the model, you can refer to it with a string.

```
class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('production.Manufacturer')
```

Will use the `Manufacturer` model from the `production` module as target of the foreignkey.

Comment: That looks like a good idea but it doesn't work for some reason: http://pastebin.com/4qvLjhr5 Any idea why not?

Comment: `models` still should come from `django.db`. In your example you're using `mcif.models.ForeignKey`. Unless you implemented your own ForeignKey, this is incorrect. You only need to remove the `from mcif.models.generic_import import GenericImport` line and replace the direct reference of `GenericImport` in the foreignkey with `mcif.models.generic_import.GenericImport`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a circular import there.

```
  File "/home/jason/projects/mcifdjango/mcif/models/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from mcif.models.account_import import AccountImport
  File "/home/jason/projects/mcifdjango/mcif/models/account_import.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mcif.models.generic_import import GenericImport
  File "/home/jason/projects/mcifdjango/mcif/models/generic_import.py", line 6, in <module>
    from mcif.models.account_import import AccountImport
```

Your `__init__.py` imports `AccountImport` which imports `GenericImport` which then again imports `AccountImport`, though I'm not sure how importing it would work at all, honestly.

Does your `GenericImport` really need to import `AccountImport`?  Seems like broken hierarchy.

**edit**: (for the updates)

```
def specific_import(self):
    for model_name in ['TransactionImport', 'AccountImport']:
        specific_imports = eval(model_name + '.objects.filter(generic_import__pk=5)')
        if len(specific_imports) > 0:
            return specific_imports[0]
    return False
```

The `eval` line reeks of bad practice.  There is certainly a better pattern here to use than this.  Your generic classes should not have any knowledge or reliance on your specific implementations, not to mention `eval` really has almost no place in real code.

Comment: Yes, I see that, but if I take the reference to `GenericImport` out of `AccountImport` it complains that `AccountImport` doesn't know about `GenericImport`. I can't think of any way to fix that problem.

Comment: I'd say your generic class (`GenericImport`) shouldn't have to know about the specific class (`AccountImport`), what does `GenericImport` look like?

Comment: Any idea what the pattern is called? I'm not a big fan of the way I'm doing it, either, but I did it that way because I couldn't think of anything better.

Comment: At this point, it's probably best posed as a new question here, I don't have the answer at the moment.

Comment: What does your mcif/models/__init__.py look like? Django will only look for models in <app_name>.models, which may explain why it can't find your models. Try importing them into mcif/models/__init__.py