# Two-way querying in Django without circular reference

Tags: python, django

Let's say you have two models: `Post` and `Category`. Each `Post` has a `category_id`.

Getting a post's category is straightforward: `post.category`. What if you want to get all the posts for a certain category? I suppose you would do

```
def posts(self):
    return Post.filter(category__pk=self.id)
```

But what if the `Post` model and `Category` model are in separate files? Because `Post` and `Category` now require each other, you would end up with a circular reference.

Maybe you say the solution is to put `Post` and `Category` into the same file. But what if your app has 50 different models, many of them quite large, all in separate files? Should you combine `Post` and `Category` into one file and leave all the others separate? Should you combine all 50 models into one gigantic file?

I'm hoping to find one of two things:

1. An answer to this problem that doesn't involve combining files
2. A good, logical reason for grouping models into the same file with one another. All my models are related to some extent, so where do you draw the line as far as grouping goes? If you draw the line with foreign keys, all my models would end up in the same file.

Comment: "you would end up with a circular reference".  That assumption is utterly false.  Why are you saying that?

Comment: I tried it and that's what happened.

Comment: Please post the code you tried.  You've got an error in your code.  All of your "Maybe you say..." to the end of the question are all based on wrong assumptions.  Please post the code and the error you're actually getting.

Comment: Let me see if we're on the same page here. You're saying you can have two models in two separate files, each including each other, and that works?

Comment: This is a hypothetical question. I'm not trying to debug a specific error. I'm trying to get a clearer understanding of the way certain Django concepts work and the philosophies behind them.

Comment: @S.Lott: I think what's he's talking about is a situation where posts/models.py has `from categories.models import *` at the top. In which case you run into problems if you put `from posts.models import Post` in the categories/models.py file.

Comment: @S.Lott It looks like this question is aimed at a more theoretical level, that came out of another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900227/django-for-some-reason-doesnt-want-to-import-one-particular-model

Comment: @Jordan Reiter: That's the wrong way to do it.

Comment: @Jason Swett: "I tried it and that's what happened." "I'm not trying to debug a specific error."  I'm confused.  Those comments seem to be contradictory.  Please **update** the question to clarify what you're really asking.

Comment: @S.Lott: Just don't worry about it.

Comment: @S.Lott right. I've run into plenty of cases, though, where model files from two different applications used models from one another. In those cases it's pretty common if you're not aware of the issue to just put an `import` statement at the top of the page.

Comment: @Jordan Reiter: "just put an import statement at the top". That's the wrong way to do it.  "if you're not aware of the issue" is -- I guess -- your point.  Awareness helps prevent the problem.

Comment: @Jason Swett: "Just don't worry about it"?  You don't want good answers?  Okay.  That makes sense.

Comment: The thing is, under normal circumstance you do put import statements at the top. The only time you can't is when these circular references come into play. Unless there actually is a pressing reason not to do imports at the top? All the source code I've ever seen in python seems to favor that approach. In terms of not worrying about it, it seems like you're focusing pretty heavily on the value of the question rather than determining what an answer might be, which might be why he doesn't want you to worry about it.. Seems to me the answer is just putting the import inside of the function.

Comment: I didn't want S.Lott to worry about it because I didn't like his sour tone and I didn't care to hear from him anymore. I didn't arrive at the answer until later. S.Lott, you might want to read this: http://books.google.com/books?id=yxfJDVXClucC&lpg=PP1&dq=how%20to%20win%20friends%20and%20influence%20people&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: "sour tone". Sorry.  I wanted clarification.  I'm not sure any other way to get clarification, except by asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to models by their name (i.e., a string) rather than the actual object. Are they in separate applications? In which case you can refer to them using dot notation as described in the [documentation on ForeignKey](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

```
#in mysite/categories/models.py
class Category(models.Model):
    ...


#in mysite/posts/models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('categories.Category')
```

You can also import the model within a function, rather than at the top of the file. I often do that to avoid circular references:

```
def posts(self):
    from posts.models import Post
    return Post.filter(category__pk=self.id)
```

Answer (score 3):

For part 1. of your question:

Django automatically sets up the reverse relationship for you. on your Category you have access to a `post_set` attribute, which is itself a `Manager`, so you can do:

```
def posts(self):
    return self.post_set.all()
```

Check out [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) for more on this.

For part 2. I have a less complete answer... If you are experiencing a need to break out models into so many files you probably have a more fundamental problem. I'd say you should think about breaking down that huge app into some smaller ones.

I think the best advice I've had in terms of reducing the size of my apps is to "do one thing". If your app can't be described in a relatively short phrase, it's worth considering how to break it out into a number of smaller apps - each of which will "do one thing".

That advice is, of course, rather loaded. It takes quite a bit of planning to figure out how to break down some complex tasks, and sometimes hindsight is the only way to see where things got out of hand. And refactoring something of the size of which you speak can be quite daunting. (If you can tell I'm speaking from experience!). My only advice in this case is to take it a step at a time. Try to break down what look like big, application-spanning issues into small, manageable chunks and do them when you can.

To address your immediate need, I'd suggest grouping your models into files topically or categorically. It might lead you in the direction of refactoring this one (what sounds like a mammoth) app into a number of smaller apps. I think that's the direction you should really be heading with this.